# Stretch <svg> inside an <embed> to fit window size

Tags: svg, stretch, viewbox

I am trying to stretch an svg document inside an  DOM in order to fit the window size.

like so:

```
<div id="y">
    <div id="button"> click to zoom</div>
    <embed id="x" src="s17.svg" >
    <script>
        var btn= document.getElementById("button");
        btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var z= document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        var y = z.getSVGDocument();
        y.lastChild.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 "+window.innerWidth+" "+window.innerHeight);
                                               },false);

    </script>
</div>
```

css:

```
#x{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#y{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This isn't working... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Unfortunately, IE9, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera all handle this scenario in very different ways.

Comment: Well I was hoping that it would work on all browsers... Should I just manually go through each element in the SVG and scale them?

Answer (score 10):

All browsers should be able to handle this just fine:

- add a viewBox to the svg element (s17.svg in your example) without using script if possible
- remove the width and height attributes on the svg element if they are specified
- add an attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg element to make it stretch even if the css-viewport aspect ratio doesn't match the viewBox aspect ratio.
- set the width/height of the embed/iframe/object to whatever you want and the svg will automatically stretch to fit

If you don't want stretching then you can also do `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` (fill whole viewport, slicing away parts if necessary) or `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` (this is the default, center the svg in the viewport and maintain the aspect ratio).

Answer (score 0):

All browsers handle SVG support completely differently.  I think your best bet is to use an `object` tag instead of `embed`,  and you still have to do some hacking to get it to look right on each browser.  [This link](http://e.metaclarity.org/52/cross-browser-svg-issues/) and [this link](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/docs/UserManual.html) have some useful information for getting it to work cross-browser.