# pdf2svg without size specification

Tags: pdf, svg

I want to convert pdf to svg using `pdf2svg` without the `width` and `height` specification that is automatically added (for the purpose to make it fit to the container along the lines of what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145867)). I couldn't find any option on pdf2svg to do this. What is the most realistic reliable way to do this? If scripting is necessary, I would use jQuery and/or Ruby.

Comment: which pdf2svg is this? Please give details. Is it the one I have written (http://bitbucket.org/petermr/pdf2svg)?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust It is the one that is installed on Ubuntu by apt-get: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdf2svg.

Comment: Thanks. Will ave a look. (mine is based on PDFBox). BTW I have no idea why people want to CLOSE this question.