# SVG image won't size up to fit parent container

Tags: html, css

I have an image (508 x 564) that I want to fit fully into its parent container.

[image]

Even with `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%`, this is the biggest the image stretches to. I'm doing a split screen style, where I'm only showing the left side of the split screen (thus, you'll see `width: 50%` in the CSS.)

HTML:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img class="image" src="path/to/image"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="textContainer">
        <h1>Some text here</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageContainer {
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image should ideally scale up to fit the parent container if I specify `width: 100%` right? I've also tried `max-width: 100%` with the same results.

NOTE: I FORGOT TO MENTION THAT I'M WORKING WITH A .SVG FILE. This is probably why it's not behaving the way I expect it to like JPG/PNG files!!!!

Comment: `background-size` only applies to background images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch <svg> inside an <embed> to fit window size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6145867)

Answer (score 3):

### -EDIT FOR SVG-

You can display svg images by either using `<object>`,`<embed>`,`<iframe>` or `<svg>` as follows:

Using the `<object>` tag:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg">
  Update your browser to support support SVG <-- displayed if svg is not supported
</object>
```

Using the `<embed>` tag:

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg" />
```

Using the `<iframe>` tag:

```
<iframe src="image.svg"></iframe>
```

Using the `<svg>` tag:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

---

### FOR THE PREVIOUS UNEDITED QUESTION:

**-For JPEG/PNG-**

Your html and css markup is all messed up. You need to:

1. Close the div tag
2. Close the img tag correctly
3. Close your css properties with a semi-colon

Like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img class="image" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="textContainer">
        <h1>Some text here</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageContainer {
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover; <!-- remove this. Only applicable to background images and not inline images -->
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/192/ <-- 50% width

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/194/ <-- 100% width

Comment: The issue isn't the syntax - take a look at my edit in the question. It's strange because I've sized up an image to fill its parent container before, but this specific picture isn't working. This answer wasn't the solution.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle links and let me know if that was what you were after homie.

Comment: Logically yes, that should be working and yes, that's what I want to achieve. My image isn't listening to me and I don't know why.

Comment: Ahhhhhh I know why. It's because it's an SVG file. I'm not working with PNG/JPG

Comment: Oh lol. You can convert it to PNG/JPEG with some image editing software or you can include the svg file using the new HTML5 `<svg>` tag.

Comment: Or you can use the `<embed>` tag too like this: `<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134813/discussion-between-homerboy-and-andrew-lyndem).

Comment: I tried <embed> including a style element (not sure if it takes a style?) but the image won't listen to the style. I also tried <embed height="100%" width="100%"></embed> but the image is still showing up as the image I screenshotted in my question.

Comment: hmm. hold on. I'll check it out in jsfiddle.

Comment: Did you target the embed tag correctly. Works fine for me on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24DNn/85/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `background-size` you need to apply the image as the background, not an element.

```css
.imageContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/50x50') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="imageContainer">
  </div>

  <div class="textContainer">
    <h1>Some text here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to scale it up to the maximum, please try the below code.

```
<img src="your-img" style="max-height:100px;max-width:100px; width:auto; height: auto; position:absolute; margin: auto;">
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple issues.  You're missing semicolons on the CSS properties, but also, you cannot use `background-size` on an image that is specified inline.

If you want that image to fill the entire container, you could specify it as a `background-image` instead and then your `background-size` property would work.  See below.

```
.image {
    background-image: url('path/to/image');
    background-size: cover;
}
```